# How to clone async_std::path::PathBuf in v0.99.10?

Tags: rust

I have a scenario whereby I want to store the value of a `PathBuf` in two different collections, in a `HashSet<PathBuf>` and as a field in a vector of structs `Vec<Contract>` (`Contract` is a custom struct defined in my project).

I looked at the [docs](https://docs.rs/async-std/0.99.10/async_std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) but I couldn't find a clone functionality for `PathBuf`.

I know that there are alternative solutions, such as converting the `PathBuf` to a `String` or generating a unique hash for the `PathBuf`, but I would prefer to use the same type.

Is it possible to clone `PathBuf`?

**Update**: as pointed out by @vallenting in the comments, I was looking at an old version of `PathBuf`. In v1.8.0 and above, `clone` is available.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `v0.99.10`? Because `Clone` is there in `v1.8.0`

Comment: No reason other than that's what Google lead me to. Thanks for your remark!

Comment: I've also just noticed the "Go to latest version" button for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `v0.99.10` you can use [`to_path_buf()`](https://docs.rs/async-std/0.99.10/async_std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_path_buf).

```rust
let p = PathBuf::from("...");
let p_clone = p.to_path_buf();
```

---

However, in `v1.8.0` you can use [`clone()`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.8.0/async_std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#impl-Clone) as you'd expect.

```rust
let p = PathBuf::from("...");
let p_clone = p.clone();
```